# How to call a function only after a SequentialTransition in JavaFX has been completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, transition, minimize

I want to minimize my JavaFX window, only after a small SequentialTransition has taken place on the whole Stage. However, whenever write a statement after the transition statement, it takes place along with the transition. The window is minimized, using the method

```
setIconified()
```

But it minimizes before the transition takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a callback with setOnFinish